Quantum espresso pseudopotential convergence test
I generated a pseudopotential using atomic code(Quantum_espresso_6.7/atomic/src/ld1.x) and conducted convergence test. But as below, total energy tends to oscillation as ecut goes up.
(I performed a calculation with a single atom, providing 10 angstrom along x,y and z axes.)
convergence threshold = 10^-9
element is Bi which i made
ecut(Ry) total energy(Ry)
10 -19.09444449
20 -19.15901093
30 -19.17330186
40 -19.17382491
50 -19.17439087
60 -19.17485511
70 -19.17484222
80 -19.17481950
90 -19.17503264
100 -19.17491035
110 -19.17501285
120 -19.17497341
130 -19.17503358
140 -19.17500213
150 -19.17507250
160 -19.17501010
170 -19.17511265
180 -19.17502749
190 -19.17509826
200 -19.17507078
element is Rh which is example of atomic code
ecut(Ry) total energy(Ry)
10 -59.73893693
20 -61.38175332
30 -61.37054733
40 -61.37198727
50 -61.37206461
60 -61.37230439
70 -61.37221574
80 -61.37232017
90 -61.37246378
100 -61.37232308
110 -61.37232873
120 -61.37247298
130 -61.37247281
140 -61.37237455
150 -61.37238007
160 -61.37247745
170 -61.37251306
180 -61.37243402
190 -61.37240547
200 -61.37245048
Plus, I tested Bi2Te3 structure. Result of theoretical lattice parameters and band calculations were reasonable compared to previous studies. And no ghost states were observed.
Can i use the pseudopotential I created for other calculations?
